# WinAPI вынести hook в dll

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook

Сделал глобальный хук на отлов нажатий некоторых клавиш. Но, не всегда срабатывает. Прочитал - надо вынести хук в dll(верно ли?). Как это реализуется?
Вот функция хука:

```
LRESULT WINAPI KeyProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) || (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))
    {
        //...
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hCBTHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Хук устанавливаю так:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) 
{
    // create window

    HINSTANCE hins;
    hins = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HHOOK hCBTHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)KeyProc, hins, 0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
    WPARAM result = msg.wParam;

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hCBTHook);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, если Вы ставите глобальный хук (то есть на все запущенные потоки), или просто на "чужой" поток, то обработчик должен быть в DLL. Для установки хука нужно вызвать функцию `SetWindowsHookEx` [ВОТ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) описание.

В приведенном коде не видно, где вы именно устанавливаете хук.

Comment: Изменил сообщение, прикрепил код.

Comment: @Range Ну вот, собственно, хук переносите в DLL, загружаете эту DLL, 3 параметр будет хэндл на эту DLL, в вторым - адрес хука (через GetProcAddress можно получить, например).

Comment: Попробую..просто никогда не создавал dll.